# Bazel build error in tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

I am using TensorFlow Android Camera Demo. I follow step given in README file.I do following things:

```
Import andorid project
Install bazel using chocolaty
Edit SDK and NDK path in workspace file.
```

While I run bazel build command :
   bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo

I getting error that **Couldn't find java at '$(ls -d C:/Program\ Files/Java/jdk* | sort | tail -n 1)/bin/java.exe'**.

My JDK is installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin` . I also set environment variable 
`JAVA_HOME="$(ls -d C:/Program\ Files/Java/jdk* | sort | tail -n 1)"` and

```
BAZEL_SH=c:/tools/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe
```

Comment: Bazel doesn't support Android builds on Windows yet. You can see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6385 for context and possible workarounds.

Comment: Shouldn't JAVA_HOME also point to 'Program Files (x86)'?

Comment: I able to fix these error by put C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin path at JAVA_HOME.